# Compute the integrals using the residue theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, contour-integration, residue-calculus, complex-integration

Compute the following integrals:

$I:=\int_{|z|=2}\frac{1}{(z-3)(z^{13}-1)}dz$

$J:=\int_{|z|=10}\frac{z^3}{z^4-1}dz$

I do not know where to begin. I know I am supposed to use the substitution $z\rightarrow \frac{1}{t}$. I can see that $I$ has 13 poles inside the circle of radius 2.

Using a hint provided by Winther I was able to get that

$I=2\pi i\cdot\sum\limits_{n=1}^{13}\frac{z_n}{13(z_n-3)}$ where $z_n^{13}=1$

Comment: Here is the recipie: 1) Solve $(z-3)(z^{13}-1) = 0$ to find the poles. 2) Compute the residue(s) of the poles inside $|z|=2$. 3) Apply the residue theorem which says that the integral is $2\pi i$ times the sum of the residues.

Comment: Note that all the poles are simple so the residue at a pole at $z=z_*$ can be computed simply as Res$ [f ; z=z_*]$ = $\frac{1}{\frac{d}{dz}[(z-3)(z^{13}-1)]_{z=z_*}}$.

Comment: Can't I factor out (z-3) since it does not have poles inside the contour? So the integral would be $2\pi i$ times $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{13}\frac{1}{(z_n-3)(13z_n^{12}-1)}$ where $z_n$ is the nth root of unity?

Comment: That is not competely correct. The residue at one of the roots of unity is $\frac{1}{(z^{13}-1) + 13(z-3)z^{12}}$. Note that the first term vanish since $z^{13}=1$ and for the second term you can write $z^{12} = \frac{z^{13}}{z} = \frac{1}{z}$ again since $z^{13}=1$ to simplify. Even with this the sum looks pretty nasty to do by hand so there might be a better way to sum the residues here assuming this is a book-problem (though I can't see it right now).

Comment: Is there any way to simplify using the residue at infinity and $z\rightarrow \frac{1}{t}$?

Comment: Ahh the good old residue at infinity, forgot about that. That is a very good idea. You can simply compute the residue at infinity + you need to compute the residue at $z=3$ (as this is outside $|z|=2$) and add them. This gives the answer directly without having to compute that nasty sum.

Comment: Perform the substitution $z = 1/t$ using $dz = - \frac{dt}{t^2}$ to get your new integrand and then compute the residue of this function at $t=0$ (this value of $t$ corresponds to $z=\infty$). I suspect you will get $0$ here so that the answer is given soly in terms of the residue at $z=3$ (or $t=1/3$ in terms of the substituted function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For

> $$J:=\int_{|z|=10}\frac{z^3}{z^4-1}dz$$

$$J:=\int_{|z|=10}\frac{z^3}{(z-1)(z+1)(z-i)(z+i)}dz$$

So the roots are: $z=1,z=-1,z=i,z=-i$

Now use the [Residue formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)) for the roots:

$$\text{Res}(f,1)=\lim\limits_{z\to 1}\frac{z^3}{(z+1)(z-i)(z+i)}=\frac{1}{(1+1)(1-i)(1+i)}=\frac{1}{4}$$

$$\text{Res}(f,i)=\lim\limits_{z\to i}\frac{i^3}{(i+1)(i-1)(i+i)}=\frac{-i}{-4 i}=-4$$

$$\text{Res}(f,-i)=\lim\limits_{z\to -i}\frac{(-i)^3}{(-i-1)(-i+1)(-i-i)}=\frac{i}{4i}$$

$$\text{Res}(f,-1)=\lim\limits_{z\to -1}\frac{(-1)^3}{(-1-1)(-i-i)(-1+i)}=\frac{1}{4}$$

So $$J=2\pi i\sum_{j=1}^{4}\text{Res}(f,a_j)$$

Comment: Why do you consider only the poles in the upper plane?

Answer (score 0):

For

> $$I:=\int_{|z|=2}\frac{1}{(z-3)(z^{13}-1)}dz$$

First you need to find all the roots that in $|z|<2$  then apply the [Residue formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)), I can't find an easy way to do this (maybe there is).

Answer (score 0):

For $$J=\int_{|z|=10}\frac{z^3}{z^4-1}dz,$$
we see there are poles at $r^4e^{i4\theta}-e^{i2\pi k}=0,$ so that $r=1$ and $$4\theta=2\pi k\implies\theta=\frac{\pi k}{2}\implies\theta\in\left\{0,\frac{\pi}{2},\pi,\frac{3\pi}{2}\right\}.$$
Since $\left|e^{i\theta}\right|<10$ for all $\theta$ then the residue theorem gives us
$$J=2\pi i\sum_{i=0}^3\text{Res}(f,a_i)=2\pi i.$$